# Declaring variables vs using function directly

Tags: vba

Is there any advantage in this:

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim LC As Long
LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LC = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
Cells(LR, LC).Select
```

Over this:

```
Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Select
```

I'm not using LR or LC anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, both are fine.

In Visual Basic dot NET, you often have to declare what a variable is going to do before using it, but this requirement is not present in Visual Basic for Application, which is a spinoff from Visual Basic 5 where it also was not required.

So, from the point of it being a requirement, no its not, and both can be used.

But there are benefits from using the dim method over the other one.

If you use the variables more than once, this is shorter to use in your code, and it allows you to keep track of any changes you make to that variable.

This is basically called business logic. It allows you to make changes to your code later without running into the fact that you refer to everything directly. If you then have to make a change or a check, you have to do it everywhere, rather than somewhere in between the code.

Secondly, this reads a lot easier, and easy to read code means easy to maintain code.

That said, I would substitude `LC` and `LR` with names that make sense for your sheet. So lets assume the usedrange is for Finance, I'd say `Finance_C` and `Finance_R` respectively.